# Conditionally summing values from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to return a total count of wins based on people with different styles fighting one another. So for example, lets assume there are 2 fighting styles a fighter can have: XX and JJ. I would like to count the number of times a fighter with XX style beat another fighter with XX style and the number of times the fighter beat a fighter with JJ fight style.

```
name  style   opp1   style   result1   opp2   style   result2   opp3  style   result3    
 A      XX     C      JJ       win      D      XX      loss       B     JJ      draw
 B      JJ     A      XX       draw     C      JJ      loss       D     XX       win
 C      JJ     A      XX       loss     B      JJ       win       D     XX       win
 D      XX     A      XX        win     B      JJ      loss       C     JJ      loss
```

This is the desired output

```
     XX    JJ
XX          1
JJ   2
```

I know I can get total wins, losses and draws by using value_counts ie

```
df['result1'].value_counts()
```

but can't figure out how to carry out this conditional summing.

Comment: I do not understand your desired output. I thought the rows where 'style', the columns 'opp1 style' and the values are 'result1'. But then then there would be a win of XX against XX and none of JJ against XX? Could you elaborate that a bit?

Comment: @maow The style is the style the fighter fights using, With my desired output I am counting the number of times a fighter with style XX beat a fighter with the same and a different style

Comment: Yes, but why is it not

```

         XX    JJ
    XX  1        
    JJ   2
```

Comment: @maow name A has style XX and beat opp1 whose style is JJ, hence the 1, not sure if that clarifies things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the format you have there is almost completely unusable. Especially columns with the same name are something that pandas can not deal with as you get naming collisions all the time. In order to work with it, you should try to cast it into something that is called "long format":

```
In [39]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[39]: 
  name style opp1 style.1 result1 opp2 style.2 result2 opp3 style.3 result3
0    A    XX    C      JJ     win    D      XX    loss    B      JJ    draw
1    B    JJ    A      XX    draw    C      JJ    loss    D      XX     win
2    C    JJ    A      XX    loss    B      JJ     win    D      XX     win
3    D    XX    A      XX     win    B      JJ    loss    C      JJ    loss

In [40]: df2 = pd.concat([df[['name', 'style', 'opp1', 'style.1', 'result1']].rename(columns={'opp1' : 'opponent', 'style.1' : 'style.y', 'result1' : 'result'}), df[['name', 'style', 'opp2', 'style.2', 'r
    ...: esult2']].rename(columns={'opp2' : 'opponent', 'style.2' : 'style.y', 'result2' : 'result'}), df[['name', 'style', 'opp3', 'style.3', 'result3']].rename(columns={'opp3' : 'opponent', 'style.3' : 
    ...: 'style.y', 'result3' : 'result'})])
Out[40]: 
  name style opponent style.y result
0    A    XX        C      JJ    win
1    B    JJ        A      XX   draw
2    C    JJ        A      XX   loss
3    D    XX        A      XX    win
0    A    XX        D      XX   loss
1    B    JJ        C      JJ   loss
2    C    JJ        B      JJ    win
3    D    XX        B      JJ   loss
0    A    XX        B      JJ   draw
1    B    JJ        D      XX    win
2    C    JJ        D      XX    win
3    D    XX        C      JJ   loss
```

Once you have that the rest is basically a oneliner

```
In [4]: df3 = df2[df2['result'] == 'win'].groupby(['style', 'style.y'])['result'].count().reset_index()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[4]: 
  style style.y  result
0    JJ      JJ       1
1    JJ      XX       2
2    XX      JJ       1
3    XX      XX       1

In [38]: pd.pivot(df3, index='style', columns='style.y')                                                              
Out[38]: 
        result   
style.y     JJ XX
style            
JJ           1  2
XX           1  1
```

The order is alphabetical, so it is not exactly your output, but the values are the same.

If you want to use `value_counts()`, you may also do

```
In [7]: df3 = df2.groupby(['style', 'style.y'])['result'].value_counts().reset_index(['style', 'style.y']).loc['win', :]

Out[7]: 
       style style.y  result
result                      
win       JJ      JJ       1
win       JJ      XX       2
win       XX      JJ       1
win       XX      XX       1
```

and get the same result after the `pivot`.

EDIT:
In [How can I unpivot or stack a pandas dataframe in the way that I asked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970745/how-can-i-unpivot-or-stack-a-pandas-dataframe-in-the-way-that-i-asked#58970806) I found a far more elegant way to reshape your initial DataFrame

```
In [10]: df2 = df.rename(columns={'style.1' : 'oppstyle1', 'style.2' : 'oppstyle2', 'style.3' : 'oppstyle3'})                                                                                                     
Out[10]: 
  name style opp1 oppstyle1 result1 opp2 oppstyle2 result2 opp3 oppstyle3 result3
0    A    XX    C        JJ     win    D        XX    loss    B        JJ    draw
1    B    JJ    A        XX    draw    C        JJ    loss    D        XX     win
2    C    JJ    A        XX    loss    B        JJ     win    D        XX     win
3    D    XX    A        XX     win    B        JJ    loss    C        JJ    loss

In [15]: pd.wide_to_long(df2, ['opp', 'oppstyle', 'result'], i=['name', 'style'], j='i', sep='')                                                                                                            
Out[15]: 
             opp oppstyle result
name style i                    
A    XX    1   C       JJ    win
           2   D       XX   loss
           3   B       JJ   draw
B    JJ    1   A       XX   draw
           2   C       JJ   loss
           3   D       XX    win
C    JJ    1   A       XX   loss
           2   B       JJ    win
           3   D       XX    win
D    XX    1   A       XX    win
           2   B       JJ   loss
           3   C       JJ   loss
```