# How can I unpivot or stack a pandas dataframe in the way that I asked?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a python pandas dataframe.

For example here is my data:

```
   id   A_1   A_2   B_1   B_2
0  j2   1     5     10    8
1  j3   2     6     11    9
2  j4   3     7     12    10
```

I want it to look like this:

```
   id   Other   A   B
0  j2   1       1   10
1  j2   2       5   8
2
```

Can you help me please. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, ['A','B'], i='id', j='Other', sep='_')
        .sort_values('id')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   id  Other  A   B
0  j2      1  1  10
1  j2      2  5   8
2  j3      1  2  11
3  j3      2  6   9
4  j4      1  3  12
5  j4      2  7  10
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) + [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to performance a [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table):

```
df2=df.melt('id')
df2[['columns','Other']]=df2['variable'].str.split('_',expand=True)
new_df= ( df2.pivot_table(columns='columns',index=['id','Other'],values='value')
             .reset_index()
             .rename_axis(columns=None) )

print(new_df)
   id Other  A   B
0  j2     1  1  10
1  j2     2  5   8
2  j3     1  2  11
3  j3     2  6   9
4  j4     1  3  12
5  j4     2  7  10
```